# Nested CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm currently working on a CSS grid layout where I want two divs in a container to be 50% width each. But I cant really figure out how.

The element `nav` has two divs inside it which I want to be 50% each, but using the grid-syntax. How would you do that?

Code:

```
$gutter: 30px;
$columns: 12;
$maxwidth: 1200px;

#container {
    max-width: $maxwidth;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat($columns, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: $gutter;
    grid-template-areas: "nav" "header" "main" "footer";
}

   header, nav, main, footer {
       grid-column: span $columns;
   }
```

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </nav
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can simply use like this**

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

nav div {
  background: red;
  height: 250px;
}

nav div + div {
  background: green; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </nav>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

To know more about [**GRID**](https://learncssgrid.com/#grid-container)

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work properly. The two divs now takes 50% each of one column of the #container. not the nav.

Comment: Add `display: grid;` to `nav` not your `#container`. @user2952238

Comment: @user2952238 in your code you add `grid` to #container`.

Comment: Thanks, works great. But why not display grid on the container as well? since its the holder of the whole grid.

Comment: When removing display grid from #container the layout breaks.

Comment: i mean if you want `grid` layout fully then `don't remove grid` from `#container`.

I mean just add `display: grid;` to `nav`. 

When you said it's not working i confused. @user2952238

Comment: Thats what i did, so now both container and nav has display: grid; but that does not make the divs in nav to fill 50% each. they just fill 50% of one column of the #container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166740/discussion-between-anzil-khan-and-user2952238).

Comment: You have the NAV badly closed `</nav`

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: fixed to say columns